# Проверка radio- и checkbox- input'ов средствами JavaScript

Tags: javascript, form

При отправке формы, содержащей чекбоксы или радио-кнопки на сервер с ними в дальнейшем работать довольно легко, потому как несколько, например, радио-кнопок представлены под одним именем (name) и имеют какое-то определенное значение:

```
<input type="radio" name="license_accepted" value="true">
<input type="radio" name="license_accepted" value="false">
```

На сервере:

```
если (поля_формы["license_accepted"] == "true") делаем какое-нибудь действие;
```

То есть сколько бы радио-кнопок не было в нашей форме, на сервер попадут только данные для каждой кнопки одного имени.

По-другому, насколько я понимаю, обстоят дела с клиентской частью. Естественно, для checkbox'ов я просто могу проверить атрибут `checked`, чтобы узнать, выбран ли какой-нибудь определенный чекбокс. Но как быть с теми же радио-кнопками? Как правильно получить значение для "массива" радиокнопок с каким-то конкретным именем?

Насколько я понимаю алгоритм действий, то для начала я должен получить все радио-кнопки с каким-то определенным именем:

```
let r = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio" name="license_accepted"]');
```

Потом нужно пробежаться по всем всем полученным радио-кнопкам и проверить, установлен ли маркер хоть где-нибудь. Потом, если установлен, нужно проверить, какой именно, и результатом для данного набора полей будет `value` у выбранного поля.

Собственно, **вопрос**. Есть ли какие-нибудь методы стандартной библиотеки для работы с полями этого типа? Если нет, то может быть есть какие-нибудь алгоритмы получше моего? Чувствую, что что-то упускаю, но не могу понять, где прокол.

Готовые решения в виде библиотек не интересуют. JQuery-подобные решения также не интересны.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * функция isCheck возвращает выбранный элемент на чистом JS без каких-либо библиотек
 * @param name 
 * @returns {Element}
 */
function isCheck(name) {
    return document.querySelector('input[name="' + name + '"]:checked');
}

// пример использования:

alert(isCheck('r').id);
```

```html
<div>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="one">первый
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" name="r" id="two" checked>второй
    </label>
</div>
```